# Mixin fields not existing on Django migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

Let's say I have this mixing:

```
class Test(object):
    ...some logic...

class TestMixin(models.Model):
    db_field = django database field

    test = Test() # not a database field

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Foo(TestMixin, models.Model):
    ... more db fields ...
```

I am having a strange issue here. If I inspect Foo through django shell I can see both fields, db_field and test

But if I create this migration:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


def custom_operation(apps, schema_editor):
    Foo = apps.get_model('django_app', 'Foo')
    stuffs = Foo.objects.all()
    for stuff in stuffs:
        print stuff.test # this doesnt exist

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ...
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(custom_operation),
    ]
```

And if I add a breakpoint at `Test() __init__` it gets called through the shell or Django but not when running the migration.

Which is the differente between with using the model through the migration?

Comment: Migrations only work for `Field` classes, which can be stored in a db column. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-model-fields/#background-theory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#historical-models

Specifically this quote:

> Because it’s impossible to serialize arbitrary Python code, these historical models will not have any custom methods that you have defined. They will, however, have the same fields, relationships, managers (limited to those with use_in_migrations = True) and Meta options (also versioned, so they may be different from your current ones).